# Add context to Toast.MakeText

Tags: java, android, toast

i would like to print a toast when i click on a recyclerview, i have an error in the variable "context" in the OnClick Method, i dont find how to fix this error.

```
private class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        int itemPosition = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
        String item = items.get(itemPosition);
        Toast.makeText(context, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // get inflater and get view by resource id itemLayout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
        // return ViewHolder with View
        v.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


    /**
     * Get the size of items in adapter
     * @return the size of items in adapter
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
    /**
     * Bind View Holder with Items
     * @param holder: the view holder
     * @param position : the current position
     */
```

Comment: getContext() ??

Comment: you can use `view.getContext()`

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Change it as follows

```
Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```